# Raspberry ethernet problem

Tags: ethernet

Hello I have a Raspberry 2b model of 2014 it has no wireless internet system so I'm with having a ethernet. First I tried to connect it to my laptop via Lan, because having no monitor and the wifi router is far from my room. The first try I did it, I made it work by editing the ethernet cable properties like address and editing the dhcpcd.conf file. Soon after it stopped working and also stopped me from connecting directly through the router, so I tried to find the problem but failed so It goes to the point I needed to reinstall the OS and repeat the process but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I also think it is the problem, but I don't know what is it. Right now I tried to reinstall the os and connected to the router directly and it works.

Comment: Welcome.  Please *edit into your question* what OS is running on the laptop and explain in more detail exactly what steps you have taken.

Comment: could also be the router ... try a direct connection between laptop and RPi

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion, as I've tested all the other forums' suggestion I come to the conclusion that the problem is within my laptop. I'll try to find it. My rpi connects directly to the router and reinstalling the rasbian there is no problem within the hardware.

Comment: I think the only modifications I've done is changine the IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, turning on wifi sharing, and turning off firewall.